# is there a way to update workspace or variable editor values during running script without a break point

Tags: matlab

I would like to update variable editor at a predefined interval during a running script without having to use a break. Is this possible? I have a sim that runs for hours, I would like to be able to come back every hour and grab some values off a matrix in variable editor to play with in excel without interrupting running script. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: save your data every hour, obviously by appropriate name. Would this do the job? This way you can grab off values from any matrix and do any operations with them. I didn't understand, <<I would like to update variable editor at a predefined interval>>. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to copy your matrix to the base workspace should do *exactly* what you want. You'd need to manually reopen the variable in the editor to reflect the new data if it's changed.

If you wanted to get fancier, I imagine you could script [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) and [`openvar`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/openvar.html) to do it for you, but I no longer have real Matlab to test with and Octave's fledgling GUI isn't there yet.

Comment: I think the Question is related to the variable browser which does not update, not to the workspace itself.

Comment: It's also about a script acting directly on the base workspace, not a function in its private workspace. Can always put a breakpoint in with a large count of reps before it stops.  See dbstop.